# how to convert binary number to double in java

Tags: java

I want to convert binary numbers into double.I have binary string

```
1100000110011101010111011000101011011000011111111111111111111110
```

I want to convert it into double value. I am expecting the Following output.

```
Output:-1.2316741412499997E8
```

Please Help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ByteBuffer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html for that task.

Here is an example:

```
public static double toDouble(byte[] bytes) {
     return ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getDouble();
}
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate how? (and use a Java 7 Javadoc as Java 5.0 is EOL)

Comment: Does that produce the number expected?

Answer (score 16):

You can use

```
String text = "1100000110011101010111011000101011011000011111111111111111111110";
double doubleVal = Double.longBitsToDouble(new BigInteger(text, 2).longValue());
System.out.println(doubleVal);
```

prints

```
-1.2316741412499997E8
```

You can't use Long.parseLong because the number is greater than Long.MAX_VALUE

Comment: Thank you very much Peter Lawrey.

Comment: @JigarJoshi Cheers. In 5th place for Java. ;)

Comment: Will this work for number is greater than Long.MAX_VALUE ? Double.longBitsToDouble(Double.doubleToLongBits(new BigInteger(text, 2).doubleValue()));

Comment: @DevanMuthunayakanSreemandira there are no 64-bit doubles which use more than 64-bits.